# Ignore spacing between echo strings

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, string, echo, whitespace

I use `echo` to print two strings into a file in either of these two commands:

```
echo -e "\n""x" >> ~/file
echo -e "\n" "x" >> ~/file
```

The first result is:

```
x
```

The second result is:

```
 x
```

<sub>I assume you didn't miss the extra space.</sub>

I most desire that the second command would behave like the first one because the extra space between `"\n"` and `"x"` makes it more comfortable to read the command.

Given it's not possible naturally in Bash 4.3.48(1), is there any syntax that will allow it or at least, come close to it?

The main goal is to have a spacing, or at least some placeholder/separator, that will give me a some kind of separation between the two strings, for more comfortable reading, but without having that extra space above.

Please show any way you know. I'm open to use something else than `echo` (though I'd prefer to avoid here-string).

---

<sub>Note, I used the term "string" for "`\n`". I'm not sure it's correct here, but it's the best term I have to describe that.</sub>

Comment: why not `echo -e "\n x"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: While I'm sure there is a way to do what you want (There is almost always a way), to be clear:  You are asking for a way to bypass the rules of the shell in order to make it easier for you to read?  What about the people that come after you and read it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it makes a single space before `x` in the second line... I don't want that single space before `x`. I want space only in the command itself for ease of read.

Comment: @Jesse_b fair point. It depends on the overall command... I don't know how it would be.

Comment: The same result could be had with `{ echo; echo x; } >file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `printf` command:

```
printf '\n%s\n' 'x' >file
```

With `echo`, I was able to accomplish this using `tr` to delete whitespace:

```
echo -e '\n x' | tr -d ' ' >file
```

Can also be written as (but please don't):

```
echo -e '\n' 'x' | tr -d ' ' >file
```

Results:

```
$ cat file

x
```

I suppose it could also easily be argued that these will actually make your command *harder* to read.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. What's the `%s` in `printf`? I didn't find in `man printf`.

Comment: @user9303970 It's a placeholder for a string which will be inserted from the arguments after the format string (`\n%s\n`). `man printf` probably documents the C library function `printf()`, but it's using the same format string placeholders as `printf` in the shell. `%s` is for "a string" while `%d` is for "a decimal integer", etc.  One could also specify field widths, left or right alignments etc.

Answer (score 3):

If the key point is visually separating the two strings (`\n` and `x`, here) in the script source, I suppose you could put them in variables:

```
str1='\n'
str2='x'
echo -e "$str1$str2" >> file
```

The parameter expansions are of course back-to-back, but the strings themselves aren't.

Or with `printf`, but adding the tailing newline must be done separately:

```
{ printf %s $'\n' 'x'; echo; } >> file
```

`%s` of course doesn't expand backslash-escapes from the argument string, but in Bash we can use the `$'...'` ANSI-C quoting that does. `echo` to get the final newline.

Or define a function to do what you want (`"$*"` concatenates the arguments to the function, without delimiter since `IFS` was cleared here):

```
output() { local IFS=; echo -e "$*"; }
output "\n" "x"
```

Comment: yes, `printf "%s" arg arg ...` is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%b` (interpret backquoted arguments) of bash printf:

```
$ printf  %b  \\n  x  >> file
```

Of course, you can quote the `\n`:

```
$ printf  %b  '\n'  x  >> file
```

But be very careful with what you feed to printf as any backquoted value instead of `x` will be interpreted by printf.

Or, since you are using bash, it allows a newline to be generated with `$'\n'`:

```
$ printf '%s' $'\n' x >>file
```

Somewhat safer than `%b`.

Or, if you want a variable:

```
$ nl=$'\n'
$ printf '%s' "$nl" x >> file
```

Or you can define a function:

```
$ separate() { local IFS=; printf %b "$*"; }
$ separate '\n' 'x' '*'
```

The `local IFS=` will ensure the arguments are joined together (no spaces in between) by `"$*"`

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is  specifically to write a newline and an `x`
(and another newline?) to a file,
without having `n` and `x` appear consecutively (i.e., `nx`)
in your command
(and without including an undesired space in your output),
a very simple approach is

```
{ echo; echo "x";} >> file
```

(to write newline, `x`, newline), or

```
{ echo; echo -n "x";} >> file
```

(to write newline and `x`, but no newline at the end). 
You can also use parentheses instead of braces for grouping:

```
(echo; echo "x") >> file
```

Note that, with braces, you must have whitespace
(space(s), tab(s) and/or newline(s)) after the opening `{`,
and you must have a `;` (and/or newline(s)) before the closing `}`. 
Or you can do two totally separate (not grouped) commands
that do redirection independently:

```
echo     >> file
echo "x" >> file
```

Or use [Jesse_b’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422525/80216#422530):

```
printf '\n%s\n' 'x' >> file
```

(to write newline, `x`, newline), or

```
printf '\n%s'   'x' >> file
```

(to write newline and `x`, but no newline at the end).

---

But if the objective is more general —
to write a bunch of strings (with no intervening spaces),
while separating them by spaces on the command line, consider

```
printf '%b' string …
```

where `%b` is the conversion format to print a string
*with* `\` *sequences interpreted* (in contrast to `%s`,
which prints strings literally). 
For example,

```
printf '%b' '\n' foo '\t' bar
```

will write <kbd>newline</kbd>`foo`<kbd>tab</kbd>`bar`;
i.e.,

```
 
foo     bar
```

(with no newline at the end). 
You could also say

```
printf '%b%b%b%b' '\n' foo '\t' bar
```

but you don’t need to;
the format will be applied as many times as necessary
to display all the arguments. 
Therefore, if you want to add a newline at the end,

```
printf '%b\n' '\n' foo '\t' bar
```

will not work; it will add a newline after each argument. 
You can do

```
printf '%b' '\n' foo '\t' bar '\n'
```

(adding a newline as a final argument), or

```
printf '%b%b%b%b\n' '\n' foo '\t' bar
```

(counting the arguments), or

```
{ printf '%b' '\n' foo '\t' bar; echo;}
```

**Yet another approach**, if you’re using bash, is

```
printf '%s' $'\n' foo $'\t' bar
```

using bash’s `$'text…'` notation
to interpret `\` sequences. 
Applying this to the original question, we would get

```
printf '%s' $'\n' x
```

Comment: Of course I had finished typing my answer before I saw [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422525/80216#422598).

Comment: Thumbed for the rich, didactic answer.

Comment: G-Man, as you suggested I checked the bytes of the files. Indeed there was a change of one byte. Without any of the two changes, at the start, the file had 2188 bytes. With `\n%s` it had 2217. I then changed it to `\n%s\n` and got 2218, so that extra `\n%s\n` is all the change. I thank you Jesse_b and G-Man for your help.